# PowerShell Read Form Pipe - not blocking one or even both sides?

Tags: powershell, named-pipes, nonblocking

The PowerShell-Script start a NamedPipe Server:

```
$Enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII
$Buf = new-object byte[] 4096

$BaseName = "testpipe"
$n = 0;
do {
     $n++
     $pipeName = "$BaseName$n"
     $delPipe = [System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles("\\.\pipe\")|where{$_ -match $pipeName}
} while ( $delPipe.Length -gt 5 )

$pipeDir  = [System.IO.Pipes.PipeDirection]::InOut
$pipeMsg  = [System.IO.Pipes.PipeTransmissionMode]::Message
$pipeOpti = [System.IO.Pipes.PipeOptions]::Asynchronous
$pipe = New-Object system.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream( 
              $pipeName, $pipeDir, 1, $pipeMsg, $pipeOpti )
if ( !$pipe.IsConnected ) { $pipe.WaitForConnection() }
echo "Connected Pipe: $pipeName"
$pw = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter $pipe
$pw.AutoFlush = $true
$pr = new-object System.IO.StreamReader $pipe
```

The PipeClient sends its Message:

```
WriteLine(PipeHandel,"Hi Message"); FileFlush(PipeHandel);
```

Now I want to read from the pipe and have found two ways 1) The Client is blocked 2) the Server is blocked?

1) This makes the PipeClient hang but the PipeServer doesn't get anything :(

```
function ReadMsg ($r, $e, $b) {
     try {
          $nTry=2
          $got = ""
          $Loops = 0
          do {
                # Read what data is available
                $foundmore = $false
                do {
                     try {
                          $read = $r.ReadAsync($b, 0, $b.Length)
                          if($read -gt 0) {
                                $foundmore = $true
                                $got += ($e.GetString($b, 0, $read))
                                $nTry = -1
                          }
                     } catch { $foundMore = $false; $read = 0; }
                } while($read -gt 0)
                if ($nTry -gt 0) {Start-Sleep -m 5; $nTry--;}
          } while($foundmore -or $nTry -gt 0)
     }
     finally { 
          return $got 
     }
}
ReadMsg pr $Enc $Buf
```

2) This let the Client send its message but the Server waits until the Client closes the pipe in the mean  time the server is blocked??

```
function rdPipe ($r, $e, $b) {
     return $r.ReadToEnd()  # ReadLine()
}
rdPipe pr $Enc $Buf
```

Is there a way that both sides send and receives asynchronous it messages?
Thanks for your help,
Gooly

Answer (score 0):

`$read` above is a `Task<int>` and not an `int`.  If you really want to use async then the following `if` should be changed to:

```
if ($read.Result -gt 0) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is not working :( If I make your change I still don't get the message. The ReadMsg function is entered but it cant read from ReadAsync :(

Comment: BUT if I place a Write-Host "READ: $read  Result: $($read.Result)" right after $read = $r.Read(..) I see: "READ: 4  Result: " - so the Problem must be somewhere else. I open the File on the pipe-handle with the flags once ANSI once UNICODE - no change, no message ??

Comment: I tried to replace $got += $e.GetString($b, 0, $read) to see what has been written to the buffer by: `foreach ($x in $b) { if ($x -gt 0){$got += [char]$x; Write-Host "$x => $got" } else { Write-Host "$b"} with the result that I get only 0 :(
                        }